# val_loss not changing according to user input but stays as its default 'inf' value during model fitting

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I am training a ResNet50 model. I wrote a callback to save the best models according to their `val_loss`.

The code is like:

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=filepath, 
                             monitor='val_loss',
                             verbose=1,
                             best = float(resume_loss),
                             save_best_only=True,
                             mode='min')
```

To set up the previous `val_loss` value I use `best`. In my example, I set it to 13.0880. However, during the fitting, it still takes it as `inf`.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEyr2.png) is the image showing that the `best` attribute is not changing according to user input, but its default value is being used.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, it is a feature.

During training, the loss from the last epoch is compared with the current loss and then it is saved conditionally. [as per your defined checkpoint]

But when you start training over again, the loss from the last epoch is considered as 'inf', and the current loss as it is and then it is saved.